# In EmberJS my event triggers all the sub-views instead of just the targeted one

Tags: ember.js

i'm learning EmberJS and building a comment section that allows 1 level of sub comments. I have an Ember View listing all the comments, when you click "reply" on a particular comment, it should display a textarea input for a user to write a sub-comment.

In my EmberJS code when you click "reply" it shows the textarea input for all the comments not just the specific one. Any advice would be appreciated :)

```js
// View
App.commentsView = Em.View.create({
templateName: 'commentsTmpl',
showReply: false,

reply: function(e) {
    e.view.set('showReply', true);
    e.preventDefault();
}
}); 

App.replyCommentsView = Em.View.extend({
showReplyBinding: 'App.commentsView.showReply'
});
```

```html
// Template
<script data-template-name="commentsTmpl" type="text/x-handlebars">
</h2>comment</h2>
{{#each App.commentsController}}
<div class="comment-group clearfix">
  <div class="comment">
    <img class="comment-pic" {{bindAttr src="userPic"}} alt="user pic"> 
    <div class="comment-content">
        <a href="#" class="comment-username">{{userName}}</a> 
        <span class="comment-body">{{text}}</span>
        <div class="comment-actions clearfix">
          <a href="#" {{action "reply"}}>Reply</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{{#view App.replyCommentsView}}
  {{#if showReply}}
  <div class="comment-reply">
    <h2>sub-comment</h2>
    <textarea class="txt-comment-reply" rows="2" cols="65"></textarea>
  </div>
  {{/if}}
{{/view}}
</div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are binding the showReply to `App.commentsView` which is the whole container. To be make it easy activate single comments, I'd suggest looking into a CollectionView, this way each of your comments will have their own view and you can toggle `showReply` on an individual comment's view.

Something like this: (Sorry, I haven't tested it)

```js
App.commentsView = Em.View.create({
  templateName: 'commentsTmpl'
}); 

App.CommentView = Em.View.extend({
  classNames: "comment-group clearfix".w(),
  showReply: false,

  reply: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.set("showReply", true)
  }
})
```

```html
// Template
<script data-template-name="commentsTmpl" type="text/x-handlebars">
  </h2>comment</h2>
  {{#collection contentBinding="App.commentsController" itemViewClass="App.CommentView"}}
      <div class="comment">
        <img class="comment-pic" {{bindAttr src="content.userPic"}} alt="user pic"> 
        <div class="comment-content">
          <a href="#" class="comment-username">{{content.userName}}</a> 
          <span class="comment-body">{{content.text}}</span>
          <div class="comment-actions clearfix">
            <a href="#" {{action "reply"}}>Reply</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {{#if showReply}}
      <div class="comment-reply">
        <h2>sub-comment</h2>
        <textarea class="txt-comment-reply" rows="2" cols="65"></textarea>
      </div>
      {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```